# Buy 3 Pay for 2 Campaign or Get 3 for the Price of 2

Tags: blocks, commerce

a block named "Buy 3 Pay for 2" shows random products from a campaign. when clicked read more... leads to a page with products in that campaign are shown. how do I make such a campaign? I'm using drupal 7 with commerce.

Comment: Should I create a new content type or Taxonomy or a new product type. I have already 2 types of products, Product and giftwrap. I want to add few products from product type into the campaign.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I'm not clear on your question.

Comment: I want to make an offer to customers, if they buy 3 items of a particular type, they will only pay for 2. This offer will be valid for only specific products. should I create a Taxonomy term or what should I do?

Comment: You should *edit* the original question with new information. That will be most helpful to frame to the question to get some good suggestions. Good luck.